# Confused by vscode delve debugger

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I have searched everywhere and tried what I can, but debugging go exes in VSCODE is just acting really weird for me.

If I step through code, the debugger seems to jump around all over the place sometimes, as though I was switching threads. Most of the time if I hover over variables nothing happens. If I try to add them as watches I just get "unavailable". I am building and running from within the IDE.

I have the latest version of go and delve. I see that I should be avoiding compiler optimisations with some gcflags settings, but nothing doing. No idea how to make progress. Any clues?

---

UPDATE: After all, this was simply a typo in the build task used by VSCODE. The problem indeed was compiler optimisations, which needed to be disabled using the following exact syntax:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Make Prog",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "go",
        "args": [
            "install",
            "-gcflags",
            "-N -l",
            "./..."
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },


    }
]
```

}

Relevant too is that I am using "exec", not "debug", to debug the executable.

Answer (score 4):

> Delve enables you to interact with your program by controlling the
>   execution of the process, evaluating variables, and providing
>   information of thread / goroutine state, CPU register state and more.

Delve will compile the 'main' package in the current directory, and begin to debug it.

For your question:-

> If I step through code, the debugger seems to jump around all over the
>   place sometimes, as though I was switching threads

Suppose you have a code in which an error occurs and your code panics then VSCode will make you jump to the panic definition defined in its core files when debugging the code.

For your second question:-

> Most of the time if I hover over variables nothing happens. If I try
>   to add them as watches I just get "unavailable".

Vs Code can only provide you the definitions of those functions which are defined in same package, So if they are defined in another package then you have to import that package, else it will show you `unavailable` function definition. So check for proper imports where `unavailable` is showing on hover.

For more information Check usage Documentation for [Delve Debugger](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/tree/master/Documentation)

**Edited**: Even if It jumps when using `F10`, Create breakpoints after the code where it jumps and use `F12` to jump to next breakpoint, that way it will not jump to a core function definition.

Comment: These are all local variables to a function.

Comment: No panics, it just steps 'through' a method by randomly moving up and down through the method lines.

Comment: @Sentinel For variables unavailability, It only happens if variable definition not found. So Please go through your files to check for imports and variable definition by searching.

Comment: Checking it all out. Give me a day or two.

Comment: OK it turned out I had a problem in my tasks.json. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Sentinel It happens sometimes.